# Python mock patch a method within a class instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I have a project assigning 2 configs in my main `__init__` file since they are used frequently throughout the project.

```
#__init__.py

from config import Config

config1 = Config('Email')
config2 = Config('Test')
```

My Config class within config.py has a method called `content` that I need to mock out on instances `config1` and `config2`.  The config does call out to a third party library to do an http request, so I need to return a `json` dictionary for the response to `content`.

In a validators function I have the following:

```
#validation.py

from parser import config1, config2

def validation(msg):
    if "email" in config1.keys():
        ...
```

I'm not trying to mock out the tests but keep getting errors.  I've tried various `mock patch` paths but none work.

My latest attempt is the following:

```
from mock import patch
from parser import validation

@patch('parser.Config')
def test_is_valid(mock_config):

    mock_config.return_value.content = "Test"

    assert validation.is_valid("email") == True
```

What am I doing wrong that my instances of Config (config1, and config2) are not correctly returning the .content values?  Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific error or unexpected result that you're getting? Have you tried changing `@patch('parser'.Config')` to `@patch('parser.config1')`?

Comment: Yes the 'parser.config1' does not work 95% of the patches I try give HTTPS unauthenticated errors since I'm trying to mock out the http request that gets triggered from config1.content

Comment: `mock_config.return_value.content = "Test"` is wrong, it should be patched as `@mock.patch('package.config.Config.content')` and `mock_content.return_value = {}`, the http request and response should be mocked as well, but without code of Config class, it shot in the dark